# How to influence the material with Geometry Proximity?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I use Geometric Nodes to make the cubes glow smoothly as the sphere approaches the cubes? The closer the sphere, the brighter the cubes glow.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would only have to capture the *Distance*, which you get from the node `Geometry Proximity`, as an attribute, and pass this to the shader.

[image]

In **Blender 3.2** there are *Named Attributes*, with which you can give an attribute a name, which you can use with this in the shader without detours.

If you are using a lower version of Blender, you would have to take the detour via *Group Outputs*.

If you want to use a uniform color instead of the individual points of the cubes, then you would simply have to hook the node `Store Named Attributes` in a different place, and apply it to the domain *Instance*:

[image]

*PS: It would be important to mention that you must use the nodes `Realize Instances` and `Set Material` in both cases.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's a good method. But I need each cube to start glowing completely, not just half a cube. https://imgur.com/a/4nQfn4q

Comment: @Valentyn All right, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much.